# Setting value of variable that is the value of another variable

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, variables, config

I am making a config/keybind system for my game I have been working on in Unity. All of the functions that control player movement/input are ran by a KeyCode variable which is simply changed to the KeyCode that corresponds to the keybind you want. The issue is, my script loads a text file formatted as (for example) "JumpKey = Space". My script splits each line of the text file as a string and converts the left and right side into separate placeholder variables with those values.

To finally set the keybinds however, you need to run code such as "controlVar = keyBind;". The issue here is that by setting controlVar to keyBind, I am not actually changing the controlling variable but rather the value of the placeholder variable. I cannot find a way to get the value of "controlVar" so that I can actually set the controlling variable that is set to the value of the placeholder.

Any help appreciated!

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Vars
    internal GameObject PlayerObject;
    internal CapsuleCollider PlayerCollider;
    internal Rigidbody PlayerRigidbody;
    internal GameObject PlayerModel;
    internal Transform PlayerTransform;

    //PlayerInput Vars
    public Vector2 MouseInput;
    public Vector3 MovementInput;
    //(controlvars)
    public KeyCode JumpKey;
    public KeyCode SneakKey;
    public KeyCode Fire1;
    public KeyCode Fire2;
    public KeyCode Fire3;
    public KeyCode Next;
    public KeyCode Last;
    //controlvar array
    public string[] controlNames = {"JumpKey", "SneakKey", "Fire1", "Fire2", "Fire3", "Next", "Last"};

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Config("keybinds");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

// Config Handler
    void Config(string filename)
    {
        string readFromFilePath;
        readFromFilePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Config/" + filename + ".cfg";

        List<string> fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(readFromFilePath).ToList();

        //if (filename == "keybinds")

        if (filename == "keybinds")
        {
            foreach (string line in fileLines)
            {
                //(re)set local vars
                KeyCode controlRef;
                KeyCode keyCodeRef;
                string controlName = "";
                string keyBind = "";
                string newLine = "";
                string[] arrayLine;
                newLine = line.Trim('~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '-', '+', '{', '[', '}', ']', '|', ':', ';', '"', ',', '.', '<', '>', '/', '?', '\u0022', '\u0027', '\u005C');
                arrayLine = newLine.Split('=');

                foreach (string listLine in arrayLine)
                {
                    if (listLine.IndexOf(' ') == 1)
                        keyBind = listLine.Insert(1, "KeyCode.");
                    else
                        if (listLine.Contains('='))
                        controlName = "KeyCode " + listLine.Remove(' ', '=');
                }

                bool validName = false;
                bool validKeyCode = true;
                keyCodeRef = (KeyCode) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), keyBind); 

                foreach (string nameString in controlNames)
                {
                    if (nameString == controlName)
                        validName = true;
                }

                if (validName == true)
                {
                    controlRef = (KeyCode)this.GetType().GetField(controlName).GetValue(this);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("ControlName \u0022" + controlName + "\u0022 is invalid!");
                }

                //finishing keycode validation later

                if (validKeyCode == true && validName == true)
                {
                    controlRef = keyCodeRef;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an easier way of going about this issue. I simply reprogrammed some of the script to check if the string value of the control matched any of the values of a string array filled with all of the available controls. For each of the lines run off of the config file, a boolean "validControl" is set to false. It then will cycle through the array and compare all of the values to the control string value specified. If a comparison is found, set it to true and repeat the process with the next config line.

I'm surprised that I couldn't find this issue anywhere on forums including here on stack overflow. Hope somebody eventually benefits from this post. :)